# Bind caching nameserver MX lookup error for Low TTL Records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, mx-record, ttl

We are running Bind (9.8) as Caching Nameserver on a CentOS 6.x based mail server. We get frequent domain not found error for certain domains resulting in mail delivery  failure. It was discovered that all those domains have low TTL values (300-1800) for the MX records  and the nameserver gives a blank answer for the MX look up query after the TTL expiry. If the name server is restarted, a proper reply is received. Ideally, the Caching Nameserver should do a fresh look up in case the cached records expire but it is not doing so in case of these domains. What can be done to fix this problem since its practically not possible to restart the caching name server every five minutes.

Thanks,

Comment: I think more info will be required. Are the authoritative servers actually providing consistent answers for one thing? Can you give an example domain for which you experience this problem?

Comment: Some of these domains are: sbi.co.in, gabriel.co.in, hdfcbank.com

Comment: And yes, the answers seem to be consistent.

Comment: You could run "rndc dumpdb -cache" to get a picture of the name server's cached lookups. Compare the NS records for the relevant domains when resolution works with those when it fails.

Comment: There was no difference.